# How to execute a multi-threaded `merge()` with dask? How to use multiples cores via qsub?

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, cluster-computing, dask

I've just begun using dask, and I'm still fundamentally confused how to do simple pandas tasks with multiple threads, or using a cluster.

Let's take `pandas.merge()` with `dask` dataframes.

```
import dask.dataframe as dd

df1 = dd.read_csv("file1.csv")
df2 = dd.read_csv("file2.csv")

df3 = dd.merge(df1, df2)
```

Now, let's say I were to run this on my laptop, with 4 cores. How do I assign 4 threads to this task?

It appears the correct way to do this is:

```
dask.set_options(get=dask.threaded.get)
df3 = dd.merge(df1, df2).compute()
```

And this will use as many threads exist (i.e. as many cores with shared memory on your laptop exist, 4)? How do I set the number of threads?

Let's say I am at a facility with 100 cores. How do I submit this in the same manner as one would submit jobs to the cluster with `qsub`? (Similar to running tasks on clusters via MPI?)

```
dask.set_options(get=dask.threaded.get)
df3 = dd.merge(df1, df2).compute
```

Comment: Have you tried `dd.merge(df1, df2).compute(num_workers=4)` ?

Comment: @Boud Where in the documentation did you come across this?

Comment: http://dask.pydata.org/en/latest/scheduler-overview.html

Comment: @Boud Thanks. I'll delete the question---I'm still not sure on the MPI front though :)

Comment: Don't delete it it can be useful for others

Comment: @Boud True---I have been just be confused by the documentation explanation. There is an entire discussion here regarding multiple cores via MPI versus simple multithreading. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Single machine scheduling

Dask.dataframe will use the threaded scheduler by default with as many threads as you have logical cores in your machine.

As pointed out in the comments, you can control the number of threads or the Pool implementation with keyword arguments to the `.compute()` method.

#### Distributed machine scheduling

You can use [dask.distributed](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to [deploy dask workers across many nodes in a cluster](http://distributed.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setup.html).  One way to do this with `qsub` is to start a `dask-scheduler` locally:

```
$ dask-scheduler
Scheduler started at 192.168.1.100:8786
```

And then use `qsub` to launch many `dask-worker` processes, pointed at the reported address:

```
$ qsub dask-worker 192.168.1.100:8786 ... <various options>
```

As of yesterday there is an experimental package that can do this on any DRMAA-enabled system (which includes SGE/qsub-like systems): https://github.com/dask/dask-drmaa

After you have done this you can create a `dask.distributed.Client` object, which will take over as default scheduler

```
from dask.distributed import Client
c = Client('192.168.1.100:8786')  # now computations run by default on the cluster
```

#### Multi-threaded performance

Note that as of Pandas version 0.19 the GIL still isn't released for `pd.merge`, so I wouldn't expect a huge speed boost from using multiple threads.  If this is important to you then I recommend putting in a comment here: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/13745

Comment: Thanks for the help! "so I wouldn't expect a huge speed boost from using multiple threads" I'm primarily using dash to work around RAM issues. While speeding up `merge` would be great, at the moment I am simply trying to accomplish a simple `merge` task.